# How do you create a text file from a batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I need a batch file that creates a text file and writes in it.

Comment: Voting to close as too broad.

Comment: It's a great question though  its structure and form was off

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `echo`, and redirect the output to a text file

```
 rem Saved in D:\Temp\batch.bat
 @echo off
 echo This is a text> file.txt
```